# Explore surrounding areas and make a map

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,
I am trying to do this task link: [link text](http://wiki.ros.org/mrp2_navigation/Tutorials/Navigate%20in%20Simulation/Explore%20surrounding%20areas%20and%20make%20a%20map), but I got the following errors

eldiwiny@eldiwiny-HP-2000-Notebook-PC:~$ roslaunch mrp2_navigation gmapping_demo.launch
[gmapping_demo.launch] is neither a launch file in package [mrp2_navigation] nor is [mrp2_navigation] a launch file name
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248070/explore-surrounding-areas-and-make-a-map/) by [marwa eldiwiny](https://answers.ros.org/users/27638/marwa-eldiwiny/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2016-11-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Marwa,
Did you try sourcing your workspace?

```
$ source ~/YOUR_WORKSPACE/devel/setup.bash
```

After that you could be able to roscd to mrp2_navigation package.

```
$ roscd mrp2_navigation/
```

---

Originally posted by [orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/26641/orhan/) with karma: 73 on 2017-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0